# JAVA type conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion, int, double, type-narrowing

I know that `Math.pow` method return `double` in java. But this code did not generate any error in my program. Does the compiler automatically add `(int)` to my code, or there is any other reason?

Before the code, I declared that
int sum = 0; and arg is array of int.

```
for(int i=0; i < arg.length; i++) {
    sum += Math.pow(2, i) * arg[i];
}
```

Comment: what is `args`?

Comment: What is the datatype of ```sum``` and ```arg``` array?

Comment: If sum is a double and arg an array of any numeric type, there is nothing wrong about this.

Comment: @SandeshGupta, `sum` is an `int`, the type of `arg[i]` doesn't matter (it is going to be promoted to `double` anyway)

Comment: @SandeshGupta when sum is int, the double result of the multiplication is automatically converted to int

Comment: Sum is int and arg is array of int. Sorry for incomplete question.

Comment: OK I got it. If that statement is sum = Math.pow(2,i)*arg[I]; there is no automatic conversion. But if sum += then there is special rule which convert double to round(double).
Thanks!! It really helpful;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to [jls-5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

the expression becomes `int += double`, and according to [jls-15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> the result of the binary operation **is converted to the type of the
>   left-hand variable**

the result is converted to `int` finally.